# count the sales of a worker

Tags: python, odoo

I am trying to count the sales made by a worker but I get the following error when using the code mentioned below:

**TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len()**

class Movement_type (models.Model):

```
   _name = 'project_rc.movement_type'

   _rec_name = 'movement_type'
```

type_movement = fields.Selection ([('purchase', 'Purchase'), ('sale', 'Sale'), ('merma', 'Merma')], string = "Movement type", required = True)

class Worker (models.Model):

```
  _name = 'project_rc.worker'

  _rec_name = 'name'
```

sales_counter = fields.Integer (string = "Sales made", compute = "get_sales_realized", store = True)

@api.depends('move_type_ids')

```
  def get_sales_realized (self):

    for rec in self:

        rec.count_sale = len (rec.move_type_ids.mov_type == 'sale')
```

Comment: a `==` returns `True` or `False`. You are asking for the length of a boolean value. You need to provide more code to actually help you further.

Comment: I just added the two tables that are used to achieve the objective of counting exclusively the sales made by a worker.

Comment: [Edit] your post and add the full traceback. Also fix the formatting – you may not have noticed it after posting, but your code displays messily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with whatever framework you are using, but if you look at the error you are getting you can see that it is correct.

On line 3, you write `rec.move_type_ids.mov_type == 'sale'`. It doesn't matter what `rec.move_type_ids.mov_type` is, when you compare it to something with `==`, the answer will either be `True` or `False`. It doesn't make sense to take the length of a boolean (t/f).

From the context, I'm guessing that `rec.move_type_ids` is a list of objects and you want to figure out how many of them have a `mov_type` property equal to `'sale'`. If that's the case, then you could easily do that with a for loop:

```
sales = []
for thing in rec.move_type_ids:
    if thing.type == 'sale':
        sales.append(thing)
rec.count_sale = len(sales)
```

If you want to get a little fancier, you can do that with a [`filter`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_filter.asp) function:

```py
rec.count_sale = len(filter(lambda x: x.mov_type == 'sale', rec.move_type_ids))
```

Comment: when I use your code I get the following error: for movement in rec.move.move_type_ids:
NameError: name 'rec' is not defined - - -

Comment: Right, `rec` was not defined anywhere but it was in your code so I assumed it existed. I think it would be helpful to take a step back and walk through your code, making sure you know what variables exist, what their types are, and what you are actually trying to do at each step.  Or, post a more complete [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with code that you would actually expect to run and work and describe how its behavior is not what you expected